# Mike Mentzer, Heavy duty

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, workout-types

I was looking for a programme that is out of the ordinary so i'm currently using the heavy duty from Mike Mentzer. My main goal is to gain mass / muscle !

It looks like :

```
Monday - back & chest :

Peck-deck 1×6-10 superseted with 
incline bench (on Smith machine, if possible) : 1×1-3

Pull over on machine, if possible : 1×6-10, superseted with
lats pulldown : 1×6-10

deadlift : 1×6-10


Friday - legs :

Leg extension : 1×6-10, superseted with
leg press : 1×6-10

stand calves : 1×12-20

Tuesday (next week) - Shoulders, biceps & triceps :

Side Dumbbell Lateral, on machine if possible : 1×6-10
lateral raise (on pec-deck reverse, if possible) : 1×6-10

Curl bar : 1×6-10

Extension triceps : 1×6-10, superseted with
Dips : 1×3-5

The form used is perfect with a tempo 4-2-4 (arround this) and each set is to the 
muscle/mental failure
```

And my question is : **Is one set for each exercice enough for breaking down the muscle to grow up ?**

Because after 2 min of rest, i feel like i can do another set.

Thank you =)

Comment: What are your goals?  The claims of these types of routines are meant to "shock" your body into growth by increasing some aspect of the intensity.  The same can be done by tweaking other aspects of the routine you were using before trying this new routine.

Comment: @rrirower, my goal is to gain mass/muscle. Because previously, i was using the standard 3/4 sets 8/12 reps. What do you mean by twerking ? like miley cyrus ? haha =)

Comment: By "tweaking", I meant to make a subtle adjustment to your current routine.  For example, for increasing mass, you should consider the 6 to 8 rep range with a steadily increasing work load.  There are other adjustments you can make, but, the point is make them when they're needed, and, don't make drastic changes.  Your aim should be to prevent your body from adapting to the work load to which it may become accustomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [guidelines from the ACSM](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Guidelines.html), one set is enough for strength gains. Multiple sets do add greater gains, but the additional improvement per set is small. [A longer article](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/LowVolumeTraining.html)  contains references to other studies showing that one set is as good as multiple sets. Note that the studies are all from 1995 - 1997.

I'm a firm believer in doing 2 - 3 sets. However the first couple of sets are done at lighter weight (25% max, 50% max) as a warm-up. I then do 1 set of my max weight.